# How to get item list from kendo ui sortable

Tags: kendo-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat, kendo-sortable

I want to get sorted list items from bind object using kendo ui sortable listview. please refer the sample code from below.

http://dojo.telerik.com/@lilan123/eWofa/2

Comment: What are you asking for here?  You already have all the items in a sorted list view.  Are you trying to save the new order of the list?

Comment: Yes..i want to save new order list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use the Kendo event that is fired on the move or change of the sortable list to set the new index value of the item in the ng-repeat that was moved.

You set the event in the "k-on-change".

```
<ol id="sortable" kendo-sortable k-options="sortableOptions" k-on-change="change(kendoEvent)">
```

Then you add the event to the scope.

```
$scope.change = function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  alert("The e object has stuff like the old index:" + e.oldIndex);
  //Get the correct item from the bound list based on index and change the index values in the list to match.       
}
```

It seems like a hack, but then again, it always felt like a hack when using Telerik controls.

Here is a good [blog post](http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/14-02-26/a-few-angular-kendo-ui-best-practices) on using the events with angular, and what they claim are best practices.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, i did it in this way but what i feel like is not angular way of doing things. 


        $scope.onChange = function(e) {

            var item = activePriest.splice(e.oldIndex, 1)[0];
            activePriest.splice(e.newIndex, 0, item);

        };

is there any other solution that we can do it in kendo?

Comment: It's difficult because you are basing the order of the list in angular on an index in the item itself, which is great.  But when you move it, you must also modify the object value of the index, and modify the value of the index in each of the other items.  Another difficult aspect, is the fact that because it's a telerik control, you are not actually dealing with the element that is bound.  They have all kinds of "magic" so that you get what you want visually, but you may not get to choose an "angular way" because you are using kendo.  This is a "kendo-angular" way.

Comment: is there any way that we can reset the sorted list?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems like a refresh on the data would work.  Like... $("#sortable").data('kendoSortable').refresh();